# Git branch name with folder creation restriction

Tags: linux, git

We follow the rules outlined below to create branches in Git:

`[bug or enhancement]\[ticket number]_[ticket description]`

In this way, the `bug` or `enhancement` is created as a folder, and the remaining text forms the branch name.

Sometimes, developers may accidentally type `Bug` or `BUG` instead of `bug`, resulting in three different folders (`Bug`, `BUG`, and `bug`) on the remote repository.

As we have an in-house Git server hosted on Linux, which is case-insensitive for folder names, conflicts may arise when fetching and pulling from Windows OS, which is case-sensitive.

Is there any way to restrict folder creation in Git, allowing only `bug` and `enhancement` as valid options?

Comment: [Husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/) might be the right tool for you. We use it to enforce specific rules for commit messages. It also allows to [validate branch-names](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-hooks-husky/#1-validating-branch-names).

Comment: Git itself does have such a feature. It only prevents a branch creation if there is any invalid character.

Comment: I think you switched up case-insensitive and case-sensitive there. Also, in git there is no such thing as a "folder" of branches. This is merely an addon of certain git clients. Which is also why there is no simple way within git to restrict this. But there may well be the possibility to do this in the clients your users use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Git is designed to work on a local system with a local repository, there are no restrictions on how branches are created, since the local user is presumed to be in charge of their local repository.

You can prevent users from committing on a branch with a `pre-commit` hook, but the user can simply rename it after the fact, or bypass the hook.  As [the Git FAQ mentions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks), there is no way to restrict a user from performing an action with hooks on the local machine or to detect that a user has done so, and in many cases these approaches are inconvenient for advanced users.  Nevertheless, they can be helpful for users who wish to use them.

Depending on the Git server, you may be able to use a `pre-receive` hooks to reject branches matching (or not matching) a certain pattern, and that's an appropriate place to implement such a policy.